# Using wildcards while using JavaScript filter function

Tags: javascript, json, wildcard

I have an array of objects in which I need to do wildcard filtering.
For example, my object might contain something like this:

```
var a = [  
   {  
      "type":"metals",
      "SN":"SN0000000000"

   },
   {  
      "type":"wood",
      "SN":"SN0000000001"
   }
];
```

My filtering function for normal criteria would be something like:

```
  var filtered = a.filter(function(el) {
      //normal checkbox criteria filter for selectedtype
      if(!(self.serialno)){
        return el.type == self.selectedType
      }
      //wildcard text filtering from textfield
      else{
       return typeof el.SN == self.serialno;
      }
    });
```

And printing out of results would be something like:

```
console.log(filtered);
```

For normal criteria filter ("type") in which i'm using checkbox criteria selection , I'm able to get my selected criteria type back(as an array of objects), but in the case of "SN" in which invokes text-based wildcard search , I'm unable to do so.

For example, If I were to key in "00" in my wildcard textfield, the function supposed to **return an array of objects** in which "SN/serialNo" contains "00" (in the example above, both objects in **var a**).

PS:

> self.serialno is a string that is retrieved from the textbox.
>
> el.SN is the array of objects returned from the filter function.

**Update:**

running this code:

```
console.log(self.serialno.test(el.SN));
```

returns me :

[image]

Comment: `typeof el.SN` will return the type of `el.SN`, which will be the string `"string"`. That probably isn't what you want? Without posting the relevant code this question may not be possible to answer.

Comment: Try using regexp, as in `return self.serialno.test(el.SN);`.

Comment: @AndyRay what relevant code would you need? What i need is a return of object results in which i searched for using wildcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from your question you `el.SN` is a string representing a set of serial number conform to a regular expression. 
If so you can use the `test` function which is aimed at testing the invoking string against a regular expression passed as parameter.

```
  var patt = new RegExp(self.serialno);
  if(patt.test(el.SN)){ return el; }
```

returns true if `self.serialno` match with the regular expression `el.SN`

You say `el.SN` is the result of the javascript filter function. I think however the `filtered` variable contains the result of that function.

`el.SN` is rather a property of a parameter (`el`) passed to the function used to filter the array `a`.

Comment: self.serialno is a string in which i extract from the textbox itself. el.SN is the results of the javascript filter function. thus im unable to use self.serialno.test

Comment: please check the updates in my answer. Thank u so much for ur time.

Comment: Hi , i managed to solve it. Need to delcare "var patt = new RegExp(self.serialno);"  and using .test method to return el back. U might want to change your code so I can mark your answer as correct. (:

Comment: you mean like this?

Comment: I mean this: if(patt.test(el.SN)){ return el; }